# Access navigation from component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to navigate to another screen inside a component but I found some problems doing this.

First off I've a "navigation.js" where all my links are, like this:

```
function HomeChild(){
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          title: "Home",
          headerStyle:{
            backgroundColor: "lightblue"
          }
        })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function Navigation({navigation}){
  return(
    <Tab.Navigator
      ...
    >
      <Tab.Screen 
        name="Home"
        children={HomeChild}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: "Home",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialIcons name="home" color={color} size={25}/>
          )
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

App.js

(obv i've more links, but removed some since they are kinda much exactly the same)

```
render(){
    const detail = 1
        
    // if(this.state.firstLaunch === null){
    if(detail == 0){
      return null
    }
    // else if(this.state.firstLaunch == true){
    else if(detail == 1){
      return(
        <FirstLoad /> //<-- THIS is the one I'm gonna navigate from
      )
    }
    else{
      return(
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Navigation />
        </NavigationContainer>
      )
    }
  }
```

And this is the component where I want to execute a navigation

```
function submitButtonTapped({username, navigation}){
  // const navigation = useNavigation()

  navigation.navigate("Home") //Crashing on this.
}

export default function FirstLoad({ navigation }){
  return(
          {/* I removed some unnecessary code for this */ }

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitButton} onPress={() => submitButtonTapped({username, navigation})}>
            <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>Submit</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

So is there any way I can navigate from this? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: You have to pass down your navigation through components

Comment: @mainak Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: submitButtonTapped, is a component of which parent component?

Comment: @mainak Inside the ``<FirstLoad />`` which is called from "App.js".

Comment: use NavigationService patterns https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

Comment: Ok got it... so what I've seen your code,  FirstLoad is a page outside of your main navigation, so you need to implement context/ redux to change the state of detail variable globally. The main idea is this. thanks

Comment: your code is failing is not because navigation doesn't exist, it's because the Home route is not being rendered since the variable firstLoad is true. To fix this, you just need to pass a function into the FirstLoad component to change the firstLaunch variable to false, then use that function in the tap event handler.

Comment: @WenW It's supposed to run the "firstLoad.js". Inside that component I would like to navigate.

Comment: You can't navigate to a screen that hasn't been rendered. looks like I was looking at the wrong variable, the variable should be detail. When detail equals to 1, you are ONLY rendering the <FirstLoad /> component. The Home component is not rendered at this point. All you have to do is set detail to 2 (any other number besides 0 &1), the Home component should render without using navigate (which you can't use).

Comment: @WenW I got ya. But the thing is. "<FirstLoad />" page should appear on the first time a person entering the app. (I just added "detail" temporarly. So ignore that for now). So when the "FirstLoad" does appear it's just a textfield where a person can enter his/her name and a button to continue. One the person press "continue" I  want it to navigate to the Homescreen.

Comment: in that case, you will need to add <FirstLoad /> as part of your navigation container, then you can use the navigation prop. All you have to do is set FirstLoad as the initialRouteName in the navigation container.

Comment: @WenW But then my "MaterialBottomTabBar" is going to be displayed. Which should be prevented.

Comment: you create a stack navigation container. It's discussed blow. You basically put the tabStack within a screen in the root stack.That way your tab bar won't be showing.  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution

Comment: @WenW Thanks to your input I managed to fix it. Thanks a lot for the help! :) Much appreciated!